# Error trying to use svgr rollup loader in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, storybook, rollup

I am using rollup in order to build a TypeScript React component library. I would like to test these components using Storybook. The `@svgr/webpack` loader works fine but if I replace it with `@svgr/rollup` I get the error:

> Module build failed: Error: Final loader (./node_modules/@svgr/rollup/dist/index.js) didn't return a Buffer or String

Since I build the library with rollup I would like to use the same svgr loader for the Storybook testing to be consistent.

Here is my `main.ts` file for Storybook

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-webpack5";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: [
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-webpack5",
    options: {
    },
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  webpackFinal: config => {
    // Default rule for images /\.(svg|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani|pdf)(\?.*)?$/
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module?.rules?.find(rule => rule !== '...' && rule.test && rule.test instanceof RegExp && rule.test.test('.svg'));
    if (fileLoaderRule && fileLoaderRule !== '...') {
      fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/;
    }
    config.module?.rules?.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      enforce: 'pre',
      use: {
        //loader: require.resolve('@svgr/webpack') // works
        loader: require.resolve('@svgr/rollup') // does not work
      }
    });

    return config;
  }
};
export default config;
```

I would expect that I could just swap out the loader used for SVG files but am finding that that is not the case.